# Awk Equivalent in perl

Tags: perl, awk, gawk

I am understanding perl in command line, please help me

what is equivalent in perl

`awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf i < NF ? $i OFS : $i RS}' file`

`awk '!x[$0]++' file`

`awk 'FNR==NR{A[$0];next}($0 in A)' file1 file2`

`awk 'FNR==NR{A[$1]=$5 OFS $6;next}($1 in A){print $0,A[$1];delete A[$1]}' file1 file1`

Please someone help me...

Comment: perl usually comes with a tool named `a2p` that automatically translates awk to perl.

Comment: Can you describe what you wish to achieve - inputs and outputs

Comment: @justintime : Hi I know awk scripting.. I am just trying to understand perl scripting in command line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the awk to perl translator.  For example:

```
$ echo awk '!x[$0]++' file | a2p
#!/usr/bin/perl
eval 'exec /usr/bin/perl -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'
    if $running_under_some_shell;
            # this emulates #! processing on NIH machines.
            # (remove #! line above if indigestible)

eval '$'.$1.'$2;' while $ARGV[0] =~ /^([A-Za-z_0-9]+=)(.*)/ && shift;
            # process any FOO=bar switches

while (<>) {
    chomp;  # strip record separator
    print $_ if $awk;print $_ if !($X{$_}++ . $file);
}
```

You can ignore the boiler plate at the beginning and see the meat of the perl in the while loop.  The translation is seldom perfect (even in this simple example, the perl code omits newlines), but it usually provides a reasonable approximation.

Another example (the one Peter is having trouble with in the comments):

```
$ echo '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf( i < NF ? ( $i OFS ) : ($i RS))}'  | a2p
#!/usr/bin/perl
eval 'exec /usr/bin/perl -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'
    if $running_under_some_shell;
            # this emulates #! processing on NIH machines.
            # (remove #! line above if indigestible)

eval '$'.$1.'$2;' while $ARGV[0] =~ /^([A-Za-z_0-9]+=)(.*)/ && shift;
            # process any FOO=bar switches

$, = ' ';       # set output field separator

while (<>) {
    chomp;  # strip record separator
    @Fld = split(' ', $_, -1);
    for ($i = 1; $i <= ($#Fld+1); $i++) {
    printf (($i < ($#Fld+1) ? ($Fld[$i] . $,) : ($Fld[$i] . $/)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply not really understood sorry, whether I have to write this many lines in `perl` for one liner `awk` ?

Comment: No, you don't have to write any.  You use the tool to generate the perl for you.  A lot of the output is boiler plate.  You can see the equivalent perl in there though.  Here, you can see that `perl -ne 'print if !$X{$_}++'` is the perl equivalent of `awk '!X[$0]++'`

Comment: Great I wanted to vote you, but since no reputation I can't vote

Comment: this tool is not helping me..I need user answers see `$ echo 1 2 3 4 5 6 | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf i < NF ? $i OFS : $i RS}' | a2p
#!/usr/bin/perl
eval 'exec /usr/bin/perl -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'
    if $running_under_some_shell;
   # this emulates #! processing on NIH machines.
   # (remove #! line above if indigestible)

eval '$'.$1.'$2;' while $ARGV[0] =~ /^([A-Za-z_0-9]+=)(.*)/ && shift;
   # process any FOO=bar switches

while (<>) {
    print $_ if 1 . 2 . 3 . 4 . 5 . 6;
}
`

Comment: You are giving the output of the awk script to a2p rather than giving it the awk script itself.  Try `echo '{for ...' | a2p`

Comment: William Pursell: Thank you.. you are Jesus for me..I need to understand `split` statement what is `-1` there ? what is `. $` and `. $/`.. I am accepting your answer...

Comment: Try `perldoc -f split` and `perldoc perlvar`.   The `.` is the string concatenation operator, and `$Fld[$i] . $,` is concatenating the array element with the content in the variable `$,`.